# How to initially hide the main GUI window with C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I have a GUI app written with C# that must be hidden off the screen when it starts (instead, it displays a tray icon.) In C++/MFC I'd hide it as such:

```
void OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);

    //Prevent dialog from showing
    lpwndpos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
}
```

But is there an easier way in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this in Winforms by overriding the SetVisibleCore() method in your form.  Some extra work is required, the native window gets created in traditional .NET lazy fashion.  The trigger is the first Show() call.  So you still have to ensure that this is taken care of.  Paste this code into your form:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
    if (!this.IsHandleCreated) {
        value = false;
        this.CreateHandle();
    }
    base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}
```

You can now make it visible whenever you are ready to by calling Show() or setting the Visible property to true.  Do beware that the Load event doesn't fire until then so be sure to move all initialization code into the constructor, where it belongs.

Comment: Thank you. I like this method way better. That is exactly what I wanted. Plain and simple.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the form's [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) and [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) properties to **false** and then simply use the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class to show an icon in the tray area.

Alternative if this will be the first form your application will open you will need to edit the `Application.Run()` in your `Program.cs` file.

Simply replace

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

with

```
MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
Application.Run();
```

Then in your form's constructor initialize the NotifyIcon object.

```
NotifyIcon nIcon = new NotifyIcon();
nIcon.Icon = new Icon(@"...");
nIcon.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I did this: `public Form1(){this.ShowInTaskbar = false; this.Visible = false;}` but the window still showed.

Comment: Use the form load event. If you want to use the constructor set the Opacity to 0 (and back to 100 when you want to display the form) instead of setting the Visible property to false.

Comment: OK. It works... kind of. My window flashes for a millisecond or so before it's removed. That's not good...

Comment: The Visible method or the Opacity one ? The Visible might show since the event triggers when the form loads. The Opacity method shouldn't cause the window to flash at the start since it will be executed in the forms constructor.

Comment: I've also edited my answer to give you a different solution in case this will be the first form your application will run.

Comment: OK. Setting Opacity to 0.0 from `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)` worked. One question though -- what if windows opacity is not supported or turned off (like in XP)?

Comment: Take a look on the second method in the edited answer, that might suit your problem a bit better. As for the Opacity question, seems like Windows XP supports opacity ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx#remarksToggle )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ShowInTaskBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) and Visible property of the startup form.

Comment: If used alone, all this property does is preventing/allowing your window to show up in the task bar. Useful for dialogs. But not to prevent the main window from showing up...

Answer (score 0):

I used this to hide a console window, (eventually).

```
private static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    public static void SetConsoleWindowVisibility(Boolean argShow)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = NativeMethods.FindWindow(null, Console.Title);

        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!argShow)
                //Hide the window                    
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 0); // 0 = SW_HIDE                
            else
                //Show window again                    
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 1); //1 = SW_SHOWNORMAL           
        }
    }
}
```

All looks a bit complicated, but's it's basically get a handle to the window and then call ShowWindow with it. As it's a console app, I pass in a command line argument to not hide the window, for debugging and such.

I put this in program.cs, decode the command line args and then just call NativeMethods.SetConsoleWindowVisiblity.

Never did find out why just setting visibility and showintaskbar didn't work. But they definitely didn't